# Is there a difference between a "way" and a "means"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

From my workbook:

> If you think that this is the most effective **means** of conveying our brand name ...

Does using *way* instead of *means* make sense? Also what is the difference between those two words and why *means* is preferred in that sentence?

Comment: This is a great question for [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Mitch ¡ʞᴉɐןɹəɯɯᴉʍp ןnoɟ ʻʎɐʍ ƃuoɹʍ əɥʇ pəʇuᴉod əɹɐ \səɥsɐןs\ ɹno⅄

Comment: @tchrist I'm leaving your comment even though I've fixed the comment it refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you think that this is the most effective **means** of

Using an agent to perform: whatever *this* refers to is used as an agent or a tool for *conveying our brand name ...*.  means: An action or system by which a result is brought about. [Google]

> If you think that this is the most effective **way** of conveying our brand name ...

Following a method, a style, an option, or such, in doing something. Doing like *this* is most effective in *conveying our brand name ...*.  A method, style, or manner of doing something: "two ways of approaching the problem". [Google]

However, note that the words have a broad range of meanings, are interchangeable  and almost synonymous in some contexts, but not in others.

Comment: The Ways and Means Committee of the U.S. House of Representatives  is responsible for all bills on taxation and revenue: how the government will raise the revenue to pay for its programs. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_Ways_and_Means) says other legislatures including the British Parliament used the same nomenclature.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus "Ways and means" is a set phrase used widely across English speaking countries. No need to consult Wiki. Shows the words are not exactly synonymous and have distinct meanings.